# Targetting the background of a div for a jquery parrallax scroller

Tags: jquery, wordpress, scroll, background

I'm trying to edit a wordpress plugin which targets the background image of the body which makes it scroll with the page. The code from the plugin is quoted below.

I want the same effect to target the background images of other divs but I can't get it to work using the

```
$(".class").style.backgroundPosition = "0px " + (0 - 
            (Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, 
             document.body.scrollTop) / 4)) + "px";
```

but its not working. I've also tried to use the DOM path to target the div with
document.div.class.style.backgroundPosition = .....

Can anyone shed some light on why this isn't working?

```
    $(window).scroll(function () {
      document.body.style.backgroundPosition = 
         "0px " + 
            (0 - 
               (Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollTop, document.body.scrollTop) / 4)
            ) + "px";
    });
```

Comment: What is the Wordpress plugin you are trying to edit? Can you post a link to the plugin?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/super-simple-jquery-parallax-background/